# Returning closure from function inconsitent with defining in place

Tags: rust, closures, actix-web

While trying to implement a simple web server application using [actix-web](https://actix.rs/docs/getting-started/), I encountered apparently inconsistent behavior of Rust closures that do not know how to explain.

I had the following code:

```rust
use actix_web::{web, App, HttpServer};

#[derive(Clone)]
struct Config {
    val1: String,
    val2: String,
    val3: String,
}

fn main() {
    let conf = Config {
        val1: "just".to_string(),
        val2: "some".to_string(),
        val3: "data".to_string(),
    };

    HttpServer::new(move ||
        App::new().configure(create_config(&conf))
    )
        .bind("127.0.0.1:8088")
        .unwrap()
        .run()
        .unwrap();
}

fn create_config<'a>(conf: &'a Config) -> impl FnOnce(&mut web::ServiceConfig) + 'a {
    move |app: &mut web::ServiceConfig| {
        // Have to clone config because web::get().to by definition requires
        // its argument to have static lifetime, which is longer than 'a
        let my_own_conf_clone = conf.clone();
        app.service(
            web::scope("/user")
                .route("", web::get().to(move || get_user(&my_own_conf_clone)))
        );
    }
}

fn get_user(conf: &Config) -> String {
    println!("Config {} is {} here!", conf.val3, conf.val1);
    "User McUser".to_string()
}
```

This code works. Notice the closure I pass to `web::get().to`. I used it to pass the `Config` object down to `get_user` and still present `web::get().to` with a function that has no arguments, as it requires. At this point I decided to move the closure generation to a separate function:

```rust
fn create_config<'a>(conf: &'a Config) -> impl FnOnce(&mut web::ServiceConfig) + 'a {
    move |app: &mut web::ServiceConfig| {
        app.service(
            web::scope("/user")
                .route("", web::get().to(gen_get_user(conf)))
        );
    }
}

fn gen_get_user(conf: &Config) -> impl Fn() -> String {
    let my_own_conf_clone = conf.clone();
    move || get_user(&my_own_conf_clone)
}

fn get_user(conf: &Config) -> String {
    println!("Config {} is {} here!", conf.val3, conf.val1);
    "User McUser".to_string()
}
```

This code fails to compile with the following error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `impl std::ops::Fn<()>: actix_web::handler::Factory<_, _>` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:30:39
   |
30 |       .route("", web::get().to(gen_get_user(conf)))
   |                             ^^ the trait `actix_web::handler::Factory<_, _>` is not implemented for `impl std::ops::Fn<()>`
```

Why does it fail in the second case but not in first? Why was the trait `Factory` satisfied in the first case but isn't in the second? May be it's the factory's (its sources are [here](https://docs.rs/actix-web/1.0.8/src/actix_web/handler.rs.html)) fault? Is there a different way to return a closure, that would work in this situation? Any other approaches you could suggest? (Notice that `Factory` is not public so I cannot implement it directly myself)

If you wish to fool around with the code, I have it here: https://github.com/yanivmo/rust-closure-experiments
Notice that you can move between the commits to see the code in its working or failing states.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then using `impl Trait` as return type all other type information other then that value implements `Trait` get erased.

In this particular case closure `move || get_user(&my_own_conf_clone)` implements `Fn() -> String` and `Clone`, but after returning `Clone` get erased.

But since `Factory` implemented for `Fn() -> String + Clone`, and not for `Fn() -> String` return value no longer implement factory.

This can be fixed by changing `gen_get_user` to

```
fn gen_get_user(conf: &Config) -> impl Fn() -> String + Clone{
    let my_own_conf_clone = conf.clone();
    move || get_user(&my_own_conf_clone)
}
```

Comment: You, sir, are my hero!